# Angular File upload formData

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I'm using [Angular-File-Upload](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload), the problem that is I can't send a formData along with the file. Following is my code:

```
 $scope.addProducts = function(){
        console.log($scope.product);
        ProductApi.addProduct($scope.product)
            .then(function(response){
                ngNotify.set('Your product has been added!', {
                position: 'bottom',
                duration: 2000
            });
                $scope.product_id = response.data;

                uploaderImages.uploadAll();
            })
            .catch(function(response){
                console.log(response.data);  
            })
}
```

What the above code does is, once the form is submit, the form will is send via api call. The response will be an `product_id` and `uploaderImages.uploadAll();` is triggered!!(This stuff work perfectly). Following is `uploaderImages` that will post file to server:

```
var uploaderImages = $scope.uploaderImages = new FileUploader({
        url: '/api/productimg',
        onBeforeUploadItem: function(prod){
          var ids = $scope.product_id
          var prodid = { proid: $scope.product_id} ---> empty
          prod.formData.push(prodid)
          console.log($scope.product_id)   ----> product_id = 32
        },
        onCompleteAll: function(){
          console.log($scope.product_id); ----> product_id = 32
        },
        onSuccessItem: function(prodId,response,status,headers){

        }

    });
```

I had no idea how to tackle this prob, `proid:product_id` return as `[object Object]`, if I assign proid as a fixed integer ie `proid:23`, it works.

PLEASE HELP!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access the value of the product_id not just the response payload:

```
$scope.product_id = response.data.product_id;
```

Also, because you are using Promises you need to chain your methods. Try:

```
$scope.addProducts = function(){
    console.log($scope.product);
    ProductApi.addProduct($scope.product)
        .then(function(response) {
            return ngNotify.set('Your product has been added!', {
                position: 'bottom',
                duration: 2000
        }, function(error) {
                console.log(error);
        }) // assuming this is async so add another then block below to execute once this is done
        .then(function(response) {
            $scope.product_id = response.data.product_id; // response.data will give you the whole response payload if the object returned is {product_id: 123}
            uploaderImages.uploadAll();
        });
}
```

Note that the error handler is a callback to the first `.then` block ([see the docs](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.4/docs/api/ng/service/$http#general-usage)).

Comment: Hi.. This solution not work out. It log an error on console

Comment: What version of angular are you using?

Comment: my version is 1.4.4 and the error is `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`

Comment: Yes sorry, try adding a `return` in front of `ngNotify.set`

Comment: And just to check is `ProductApi.addProduct` using `$http`?

Comment: is the second `.then` encapsulate within the first one?

Comment: yes, `addProduct: function(productData){
    //console.log($scope.user);
    return $http.put('/api/product',productData);
   }`

Comment: No it could be but only if `ngNotify.set` is using `$http` or `$q` i.e. it returns a promise. if it does not return a promise then you will not have access to the `.then` and `.catch` methods

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91394/discussion-between-br3w5-and-ngman).